# Use of typeclasses in the JSON example form Real World Haskell

Tags: json, haskell

I have found [Real World Haskell - Chapter 5](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/writing-a-library-working-with-json-data.html) mainly confusing, and it seems it is stinging me also in [Chapter 6](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html).

In [Chapter 6](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html), up to just before *Typeclasses at work: making JSON easier to use*, everything seems clear to me; then the book shows a portion of a JSON file, as well as a Haskell source that defines a variable `result` holding (most of) that JSON example.

Then, with reference to the preceding chunk of code, it makes the difference between JSON objects, which can contain elements of different types, and Haskell lists, which cannot. This justifies the use of `JValue`'s constructors (`JNumber`, `JBool`, ...) in the aforementioned code.

So far so good. Then it starts becoming confusing form me.

> This limits our flexibility: if we want to change the number `3920` to a string `"3,920"`, we must change the constructor that we use to wrap it from `JNumber` to `JString`.

Yeah, so what? If my intention is to make this change, I will have to change, for instance, this line

```
("esitmatedCount", JNumber 3920)
```

to this

```
("esitmatedCount", JString "3,920")
```

which corresponds to changing `3920` to `"3,920"` in the actual JSON file. So what? If I had the chance of putting different types in a Haskell list, I would still have to wrap the number in the double quotes and add the comma.

**I don't get where the loss of flexibility is.**

Then a *tempting* solution is proposed (*tempting*? Than it is no good... Where's the drawback? Some comments in the online book pose the same question.)

> ```
> type JSONError = String
>
> class JSON a where
>     toJValue :: a -> JValue
>     fromJValue :: JValue -> Either JSONError a
>
> instance JSON JValue where
>     toJValue = id
>     fromJValue = Right
> ```
>
> Now, instead of applying a constructor like `JNumber` to a value to wrap it, we apply the `toJValue` function. If we change a value's type, the compiler will choose a suitable implementation of `toJValue` to use with it.

This makes me thing that the intention is to use the `toJValue` function **instead** of the constructor `JNumber`, but I don't see how `toJValue 3920` could work.

**How should I make use of the code above?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update:* I added answers to your follow-up comments in a section at the end.

I think the authors, in writing the type classes chapter, wanted to maintain continuity with the example from the previous chapter. They may also have had in mind some real code they'd written where type classes were used for working with JSON in Haskell. (I see that Bryan O'Sullivan, one of the authors of RWH, is also the author of the excellent `aeson` JSON parsing library which uses type classes extremely effectively.)  I think that they were also a little frustrated that their best example of the need for type classes (`BasicEq`) was something that was already implemented, which forced readers to pretend that the language designers had left a key feature out of the language in order to see the need for type classes.  They also realized that the JSON example was rich and complex enough to allow them to introduce some difficult new concepts (type synonym and overlapping instances, the open world assumption, newtype wrappers, etc.).

So, they tried to add the JSON example as a realistic, reasonably complex example that related back to the earlier material and could be used for pedagogical purposes to introduce a bunch of new material.

Unfortunately, they realized a little too late that the motivation for the example was weak, at least without introducing a bunch of advanced new concepts and techniques.  So, they mumbled something about "lack of flexibility", forged ahead anyway, and let the example peter out at the end, never really getting back to how someone would use `toJValue` or `fromJValue` for anything.

Here's a demonstration of why the `JSON` class is useful, motivated by the `aeson` package.  Note that it uses several more advanced features that haven't been covered by the first five chapters of RWH, so you might not be able to follow it all yet.

So we're on the same page, suppose we have the following code, a slightly simplified version of the type class and instances from Chapter 6.  There are a few extra the language extensions here that are needed for the code below.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances, RankNTypes, RecordWildCards #-}

module JSONClass where

data JValue = JString String
            | JNumber Double
            | JBool Bool
            | JNull
            | JObject [(String, JValue)]
            | JArray [JValue]
  deriving (Show)

class JSON a where
  toJValue :: a -> JValue
  fromJValue :: JValue -> Maybe a
instance JSON Bool where
  toJValue = JBool
  fromJValue (JBool b) = Just b
  fromJValue _ = Nothing
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} JSON String where
  toJValue = JString
  fromJValue (JString s) = Just s
  fromJValue _ = Nothing
instance JSON Double where
  toJValue = JNumber
  fromJValue (JNumber x) = Just x
  fromJValue _ = Nothing
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (JSON a) => JSON [a] where
  toJValue = JArray . map toJValue
  fromJValue (JArray vals) = mapM fromJValue vals
  fromJValue _ = Nothing
```

Also suppose that we have some Haskell data types representing search results, patterned after the `result` example given in the "Typeclasses at work" section:

```
data Search = Search
  { query :: String
  , estimatedCount :: Double
  , moreResults :: Bool
  , results :: [Result]
  } deriving (Show)
data Result = Result
  { title :: String
  , snippet :: String
  , url :: String
  } deriving (Show)
```

It would be nice to convert these to JSON.  Using the `RecordWildCards` extension which "blows up" the fields of a parameter into separate variables, we can write this quite cleanly:

```
resultToJValue :: Result -> JValue
resultToJValue Result{..}
  = JObject [("title", JString title), ("snippet", JString snippet), ("url", JString url)]
searchToJValue :: Search -> JValue
searchToJValue Search{..}
  = JObject [("query", JString query),
             ("estimatedCount", JNumber estimatedCount),
             ("moreResults", JBool moreResults),
             ("results", JArray $ map resultToJValue results)]
```

It's a little cluttered with constructors.  We could "simplify" this by replacing some of the constructors with `toJValue` which would give us:

```
resultToJValue :: Result -> JValue
resultToJValue Result{..}
  = JObject [("title", toJValue title), ("snippet", toJValue snippet),
                 ("url", toJValue url)]
searchToJValue :: Search -> JValue
searchToJValue Search{..}
  = JObject [("query", toJValue query),
             ("estimatedCount", toJValue estimatedCount),
             ("moreResults", toJValue moreResults),
             ("results", JArray $ map resultToJValue results)]
```

You could easily argue that's really no less cluttered.  However, the type class allows us to define a helper function:

```
(.=) :: (JSON a) => String -> a -> (String, JValue)
infix 0 .=
k .= v = (k, toJValue v)
```

which introduces a nice, clean syntax:

```
resultToJValue :: Result -> JValue
resultToJValue Result{..}
  = JObject [ "title" .= title
            , "snippet" .= snippet
            , "url" .= url ]
searchToJValue :: Search -> JValue
searchToJValue Search{..}
  = JObject [ "query" .= query
            , "estimatedCount" .= estimatedCount
            , "moreResults" .= moreResults
            , ("results", JArray $ map resultToJValue results)]
```

and the only reason the last line looks ugly is that we didn't give `Result` its `JSON` instance:

```
instance JSON Result where
  toJValue = resultToJValue
```

which would allow us to write:

```
searchToJValue :: Search -> JValue
searchToJValue Search{..}
  = JObject [ "query" .= query
            , "estimatedCount" .= estimatedCount
            , "moreResults" .= moreResults
            , "results" .= results ]
```

In fact, we don't need the functions `resultToJValue` and `searchToJValue` at all, as their definitions can just be given directly in the instances.  So, all the code above after the definitions of the `Search` and `Result` data types can be collapsed down to:

```
(.=) :: (JSON a) => String -> a -> (String, JValue)
infix 0 .=
k .= v = (k, toJValue v)

instance JSON Result where
  toJValue Result{..}
    = JObject [ "title" .= title
              , "snippet" .= snippet
              , "url" .= url ]
instance JSON Search where
  toJValue Search{..}
    = JObject [ "query" .= query
              , "estimatedCount" .= estimatedCount
              , "moreResults" .= moreResults
              , "results" .= results ]
```

which provides support for:

```
search = Search "awkward squad haskell" 3920 True
           [ Result "Simon Peyton Jones: papers"
                    "Tackling the awkward squad..."
                    "http://..."
           ]

main = print (toJValue search)
```

What about converting a JSON `JValue` back to `Result` and `Search`?  You might want to try writing this up without using the type classes and see what it looks like.  The solution with type classes uses a mind-bending helper function (that requires the `RankNTypes` language extension):

```
withObj :: (JSON a) => JValue ->
           ((forall v. JSON v => String -> Maybe v) -> Maybe a) -> Maybe a
withObj (JObject lst) template = template v
  where v k = fromJValue =<< lookup k lst
```

after which the instances are easily written using applicative syntax (`<$>` and `<*>`) which allow us to combine a bunch of `Maybe` values as paramters to a function call, returning `Nothing` if any of the parameters are `Nothing` (i.e., unexpected type in the JSON) and calling the function otherwise:

```
instance JSON Result where
  fromJValue o = withObj o $ \v -> Result <$> v "title" <*> v "snippet" <*> v "url"
instance JSON Search where
  fromJValue o = withObj o $ \v -> Search <$> v "query" <*> v "estimatedCount"
    <*> v "moreResults" <*> v "results"
```

Without type classes, this sort of uniform treatment of different field types using the helper functions `(.=)` and `withObj` wouldn't have been possible and the final syntax for writing these marshalling functions would have been substantially more complicated.

This example couldn't have been introduced as-is in RWH Chapter 6, as it involves applicatives (the `<*>` syntax), higher rank types (`withObj`), and probably a bunch of other things I've forgotten about.  I'm not sure if it could be simplified enough to make the final syntax look nice enough that the advantages of using type classes would be clear.

Anyway, here's the full code.  You might want to browse the documentation for the `aeson` package to see what a *real* library based on this approach would look like.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances, RankNTypes, RecordWildCards #-}

module JSONClass where

-- JSON type
data JValue = JString String
            | JNumber Double
            | JBool Bool
            | JNull
            | JObject [(String, JValue)]
            | JArray [JValue]
  deriving (Show)

-- Type classes and instances
class JSON a where
  toJValue :: a -> JValue
  fromJValue :: JValue -> Maybe a
instance JSON Bool where
  toJValue = JBool
  fromJValue (JBool b) = Just b
  fromJValue _ = Nothing
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} JSON String where
  toJValue = JString
  fromJValue (JString s) = Just s
  fromJValue _ = Nothing
instance JSON Double where
  toJValue = JNumber
  fromJValue (JNumber x) = Just x
  fromJValue _ = Nothing
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (JSON a) => JSON [a] where
  toJValue = JArray . map toJValue
  fromJValue (JArray vals) = mapM fromJValue vals
  fromJValue _ = Nothing

-- helpers
(.=) :: (JSON a) => String -> a -> (String, JValue)
infix 0 .=
k .= v = (k, toJValue v)
withObj :: (JSON a) => JValue ->
           ((forall v. JSON v => String -> Maybe v) -> Maybe a) -> Maybe a
withObj (JObject lst) template = template v
  where v k = fromJValue =<< lookup k lst

-- our new data types
data Search = Search
  { query :: String
  , estimatedCount :: Double
  , moreResults :: Bool
  , results :: [Result]
  } deriving (Show)
data Result = Result
  { title :: String
  , snippet :: String
  , url :: String
  } deriving (Show)

-- JSON instances to marshall them in and out of JValues
instance JSON Result where
  toJValue Result{..}
    = JObject [ "title" .= title
              , "snippet" .= snippet
              , "url" .= url ]
  fromJValue o = withObj o $ \v -> Result <$> v "title" <*> v "snippet" <*> v "url"
instance JSON Search where
  toJValue Search{..}
    = JObject [ "query" .= query
              , "estimatedCount" .= estimatedCount
              , "moreResults" .= moreResults
              , "results" .= results ]
  fromJValue o = withObj o $ \v -> Search <$> v "query" <*> v "estimatedCount"
    <*> v "moreResults" <*> v "results"

-- a test
search :: Search
search = Search "awkward squad haskell" 3920 True
           [ Result "Simon Peyton Jones: papers"
                    "Tackling the awkward squad..."
                    "http://..."
           ]
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let jsonSearch = toJValue search
  print jsonSearch
  let search' = fromJValue jsonSearch :: Maybe Search
  print search'
```

#### Answers to Questions from the Comments

You asked a bunch of follow-up questions in the comments.  I've tried to answer them here, in slightly different order:

Q:  The book uses `Either` and you use `Maybe`. I would say that's just because you are using `Nothing` to say something went wrong and the book suggests using an explanatory `String` to give details about the wrong.  Ok, but the book's definition of `toJValue` and `fromJValue` are so different from yours: I can't see how `toJValue = id` can be useful as the type of input and output cannot be different, based on `id`'s signature; and `fromJValue`, given any `JValue` returns `Right` that `JValue`, whereas you deconstruct to return the Haskell type wrapped in it.

A:  Yes, I used `Maybe` instead of `Either` to signal errors, and only because I thought it made my example a little bit simpler.  The book talks about this in the "More helpful errors" section, noting that `Maybe` could have been used, too, but `Either` allows more helpful error messages to be provided:  the book's `Left` is like my `Nothing` but with an additional explanatory note.

Maybe my plan to simplify things backfired because my version is supposed to look similar to the book's version.  I think you're just comparing the wrong instances.  Consider the `class` definitions first:

```
-- from book
class JSON a where
    toJValue :: a -> JValue
    fromJValue :: JValue -> Either JSONError a
-- mine
class JSON a where
  toJValue :: a -> JValue
  fromJValue :: JValue -> Maybe a
```

The only intended difference here is that `fromJValue` can return `Left errmsg` or `Right answer` in the book's version *versus* `Nothing` or `Just answer` in my version.  For a particular instance, like the `Bool` instance, we have:

```
-- from book
instance JSON Bool where
    toJValue = JBool
    fromJValue (JBool b) = Right b
    fromJValue _ = Left "not a JSON boolean"
-- mine
instance JSON Bool where
  toJValue = JBool
  fromJValue (JBool b) = Just b
  fromJValue _ = Nothing
```

Again, these match except that `Right` becomes `Just` and `Left "message"` becomes `Nothing`.  I think all that's throwing you off is that the book defines this extra instance for the `JValue` type:

```
instance JSON JValue where
    toJValue = id
    fromJValue = Right
```

that I decided not to define because I didn't need it for anything.  This instance is weird and different from all the other instances.  All the other instances involve translating other Haskell types to and from a corresponding `JValue` representation.  This instance "translates" a `JValue` to and from itself.  So, `toJValue` is just `id` because no transformation is actually needed.  For `fromJValue`, we'd be tempted to use `id`, too, but the general `fromJValue` function is allowed to fail by returning `Left errmsg` (or `Nothing`, for my version) if the types don't match.  But, a `JValue` is always the right type to be "translated" to a `JValue`, so we can always return a `Right` answer.  My version of this instance would look like:

```
instance JSON JValue where
    toJValue = id
    fromJValue = Just  -- use Just instead of Right; we never return Nothing
```

Q:  Also, you put `fromJValue _ = Nothing` in every instance, whereas the book doesn't even mention `Left`, not before "More Helpful Errors". Maybe I have to keep reading a bit, as understanding half of your answer has hopefully unlocked something in my understanding.

A:  Well, the book only introduces one instance before the "More helpful errors" section, and it's that `instance JSON JValue`.  My version wouldn't have needed `Nothing`, the same way the book's didn't need `Left`.  As soon as we start defining instances that can fail, then we need either `Left` or `Nothing`.

Q:  The other concerns `mapM`: why is that used? I understand that `vals` is a valid list in input to the `JArray` constructor (otherwise we couldn't be on the lines which deconstructs it, right?), so applying `fromJValue` to each element of the list should return a `Maybe` (all `Just`, right?) just as the signature of the function requires.

A:  Yes, you're correct.  You're just missing one step.  To be concrete, let's say we're trying to read a Haskell list of doubles (`[Double]`) from a JSON value like:

```
JArray [JNumber 1.0, JNumber 2.0, JNumber 3.0]
```

so we have `vals = [JNumber 1.0, JNumber 2.0, JNumber 3.0]`.  As you say, we want to apply `fromJValue` to each element of this list.  If we did that using `map`, like:

```
map fromJValue vals
```

we'd get:

```
[Just 1.0, Just 2.0, Just 3.0] :: [Maybe Double]
```

but that return value *doesn't* actually match the type signature.  That's a `[Maybe Double]` value, but we want a `Maybe [Double]` value, more like:

```
Just [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] :: Maybe [Double]
```

The purpose of `mapM` here is to pull that "Just" outside of the list.  It serves a second purpose, too.  If we were trying to read a list like:

```
[JNumber 1.0, JNumber 2.0, JString "three point zero"]
```

then applying `map fromJValue vals` (in a context where `fromJValue` has been specialized to the `Double` instance) would give:

```
[Just 1.0, Just 2.0, Nothing] :: [Maybe Double]
```

Here, even though *some* of the elements were successfully transformed to doubles, some couldn't be, so we actually want to indicate overall failure by transforming that whole thing into the final result:

```
Nothing :: Maybe [Double]
```

The `mapM` function is a general monadic map, but for the specific monad I'm using (the `Maybe` monad), it has signature:

```
mapM :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe [b]
```

It's best understood as using a function `a -> Maybe b` that can "succeed" by returning `Just` or "fail" by returning `Nothing`, and applying that function to a list `[a]`.  If **all** applications succeed, it returns `Just` the list of the results (pulling the `Just` outside the list); if **any** fail, it returns a global `Nothing` failure value.

It's actually the same idea as the function `mapEithers` in RWH.  That function applies a function to the list `[a]`, and if they **all** succeed (by returning `Right`s), it returns `Right` the list of the results (pulling the `Right` outside the list); if **any** fail (by returning `Left`), it returns a `Left` failure value (using the "first" error message encountered, if multiple errors are generated).  In fact, `mapEithers` didn't need to be defined.  It could have been replaced with `mapM`, because `mapM` works with both the `Maybe` monad and the `Either errmsg` monads and has the same behavior as `mapEithers` for the `Either errmsg` monad.

Q:  One concerns `JNull`, which is the only constructor not taking any parameters, so there's nothing to deconstruct and, therefore, no type that could be made an instance of `JSON`. How does this fit the overall picture?

A:  The most literal way of translating `JNull` would be to translate it into a Haskell type that contains no information.  There actually is such a type.  It's named "unit" and written `()` in source code.  You've probably seen it used in various contexts.  The appropriate instance would be:

```
instance JSON () where
  toJValue () = JNull
  fromJValue JNull = Just ()
  fromJValue _ = Nothing
```

I didn't include this instance because it's pretty useless.  It would only be helpful for translating to and from some JSON where a particular field always had the explicit value `null`, but that's not the way `null` is used in JSON.

At the risk of complicating things further, here is a potential use for `JNull`.  Suppose I wanted to add an optional field to my `Result` type, for the URL of a "favorites icon" or something.

```
data Result = Result
  { title :: String
  , snippet :: String
  , url :: String
  , favicon :: Maybe String   -- new, optional field
  } deriving (Show)
```

Now, my beautiful `instance JSON Result` is broken, because I don't have a way of handling a `Maybe String` field.  But, I can introduce a new instance to handle `Maybe` values that uses `JNull` as the equivalent of `Nothing`:

```
instance JSON a => JSON (Maybe a) where
  toJValue Nothing = JNull
  toJValue (Just x) = toJValue x
  fromJValue JNull = Just Nothing
  fromJValue x = Just <$> fromJValue x
```

There are many complicated things going on here, and I won't try to explain them all.  However, it may help to understand that the return value of `fromJValue` is the rather weird type `Maybe (Maybe a)` where the two `Maybe`s serve different purposes: the outer `Maybe` says whether the transformation succeeded, and the inner `Maybe` says whether the optional value was available or missing.  So `Just Nothing` is a value representing a successful transformation to a missing value!

The point of that instance is that we can update our `Result` instance to include the new field:

```
instance JSON Result where
  toJValue Result{..}
    = JObject [ "title" .= title
              , "snippet" .= snippet
              , "url" .= url
              , "favicon" .= favicon ]
  fromJValue o = withObj o $ \v -> Result <$> v "title" <*> v "snippet"
                                   <*> v "url" <*> v "favicon"
```

and the instance can now (sort of) handle an optional value:

```
> toJValue (Result "mytitle" "mysnippet" "myurl" Nothing)
JObject [("title",JString "mytitle"),("snippet",JString "mysnippet"),("url",JString "myurl"),("favicon",JNull)]
> toJValue (Result "mytitle" "mysnippet" "myurl" (Just "myfavicon"))
JObject [("title",JString "mytitle"),("snippet",JString "mysnippet"),("url",JString "myurl"),("favicon",JString "myfavicon")]
```

though in generating real JSON, you probably would leave out any fields that looked like `{ ..., favicon: null, ... }`, so you'd want to introduce some filtering to remove null fields from the final JSON value.  Also, `fromJValue` doesn't actually handle a truly *missing* optional field:

```
> fromJValue (JObject [("title",JString "mytitle"),("snippet",JString "mysnippet"),("url",JString "myurl")]) :: Maybe Result
Nothing
```

Instead, it needs an explicit `JNull` to work correctly:

```
> fromJValue (JObject [("title",JString "mytitle"),("snippet",JString "mysnippet"),("url",JString "myurl"),("favicon",JNull)]) :: Maybe Result
Just (Result {title = "mytitle", snippet = "mysnippet", url = "myurl", favicon = Nothing})
```

so we'd need to do a bit more coding to get this to work properly.

Comment: Despite I have to give up, for now, on the second part of your answer (_What about converting a JSON `JValue` back to `Result` and `Search`?_), since it brings in too much stuff that I don't know, based on the first part I can say that, upon a careful reading, the answer seems very clear, hence my +1. I have just a few doubts about this first part, listed in the following comment.

Comment: One concerns `JNull`, which is the only constructor not taking any paramters, so there's nothing to deconstruct and, therefore, no type that could be made an `instance` of `JSON`. How does this fit the overall picture?
The other concerns `mapM`: why is that used? I understand that `vals` is a valid list in input to the `JArray` constructor (otherwise we couldn't be on the lines which deconstructs it, right?), so applying `fromJValue` to each element of the list should return a `Maybe` (all `Just`, right?) just as the signature of the function requires.

Comment: Oh, one more doubt. The book uses `Either` and you use `Maybe`. I would say that's just because you are using `Nothing` to say something when wrong and the book suggests using an explanatory `String` to give details about the _wrong_. Ok, but the book's definition of `toJValue` and `fromJValue` are so different from yours: I can't see how `toJValue = id` can be useful as the type of input and output cannot be different, based on `id`'s signature; and `fromJValue`, given any `JValue` returns `Right` that `JValue`, whereas you deconstruct to return the Haskell type wrapped in it.

Comment: Also, you put `fromJValue _ = Nothing` in every instance, whereas the book doesn't even mention `Left`, not before _More Helpful Errors_. Maybe I have to keep reading a bit, as understanding half of your answer has hopefully unlocked something in my understanding.

Comment: I've added a section at the end of my answer to try to answer these.

Comment: Well, what can I say beside accepting the answer? I will often need to come back to this in the future. Thank you very much for the effort you put into writing this. I hope it'll be useful to many other people.